# The method put(String, List<String>) is not applicable

Tags: java

Hi all im having this kind of error on my code:

The method put(String, List) in the type HashMap> is not applicable for the arguments (String, List>)

My code is here:

```
private void prepareListData() {


    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("VRP Medical Bay");
    //listDataHeader.add("");
    //listDataHeader.add("");

    // Adding child data
    List<HashMap<String, String>> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //List<String> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<String>();
    com.test.utilities.XMLParser parser = new com.test.utilities.XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        listUnderVRP.add(map);

    }


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), listUnderVRP); // Header, Child data
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
```

im getting error on the put function.

heres the whole logic of my code, im having problem integrating my xml files to my listview. the flow is like this: i got navigation drawer inside it i got expandable list, inside expandable list i got listview, which i get the data on my xml api to display on the list view.ive work with for 3 days but to no luck.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

static final String URL = "http://api.test.info/test/test.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "elements"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;

public DrawerLayout drawer;
ImageView navDrawerBtn;

HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
List<String> listDataHeader;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    navDrawerBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.headerDrawer);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(402,465);    
    } else {        
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(402,465);    
    } 

    drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    prepareListData();



    navDrawerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!drawer.isDrawerOpen(expListView)) {
                drawer.openDrawer(expListView);
                } else {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(expListView);
                }

            }
        });


    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {


    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("VRP Medical Bay");
    //listDataHeader.add("");
    //listDataHeader.add("");

    // Adding child data
    List<HashMap<String, String>> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //List<String> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<String>();
    com.test.utilities.XMLParser parser = new com.test.utilities.XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        listUnderVRP.add(map);

    }


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), listUnderVRP); // Header, Child data
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}

 public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
        // Get the screen's density scale 
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
        return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
    }
```

}

Comment: What type does `parser.getValue()` return?

Comment: hi @Bohemian, i updated my code, i added the whole logic

Comment: You haven't posted the definition of `getValue()` - what is it's return type?

Comment: the return type is xml data

Comment: Again what is the declared return type? String? What class?

Comment: sorry the return type is string

Comment: And which line is causing the problem? What's the name of the variable you're attempting to call `put()` on

Comment: those with get and put function: it says: The method get(int) in the type List<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)/The method put(String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined for the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Answer (score 1):

the main reason is your listDataChild only allow `List<String>` type, but your input param (listUnderVRP) has  `List<HashMap<String, String>>` so try this:

replace:

```
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

by:

```
listDataChild = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I base on what you supply, not sure it appropriate for your business logic.

Comment: hi @Tien, i updated my code, i added the whole logic

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing the HashMap as a `HashMap<String, String>` not a `HashMap<String, List<?>>`.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Presumably parser is returning a List of some kind and so you have a type error.

Answer (score 0):

There's too much code to wade through, but based on your comments:

> The method get(int) in the type List> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Would be caused by attempting to call `get(i)` where `i` is a `String`, when it should be an `int`.

> The method put(String, ArrayList>) is undefined for the type ArrayList>

Would be caused by attempting to use the *Map* method `put(K, V)` on a *List*, which only has the `add()` method.

Comment: yes i believe you so, im trying to fix my code, but still to no luck, im not familiar with how to use those types, my goal is only to display my data on a expandable list from a xml service

Answer (score -1):

replace:

```
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

by:

```
listDataChild = new ArrayList<String, Object>();
```